# Segmentation fault by using pointer to pointer

Tags: c

I have the following program which uses a pointer to pointer to print the different elements of a 2D array `U`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myfunction(double **U) {
    printf("%f\n", U[0][0]); //correctly prints U[0][0]
    printf("%f\n", U[0][1]); //correctly prints U[0][1]
    printf("%f\n", U[1][0]); //"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
    return 0;
}

int main(void){    
    double U[3][4] = {{10, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 6, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 5, 0}};
    double **pU = U;

    myfunction(&pU);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code gives the following output:

```
10.00000
1.00000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is it that `**U` seemingly can only access the first row of the matrix? What should I do differently so that `printf("%f\n", U[1][0]);` prints the correct value?

Comment: Wouldn't `&pU` be a `double***` (3 stars)?

Comment: `double **U` does not tell the function anything about the matrix dimensions.

Comment: @WeatherVane What can I do instead? :/

Comment: Define `int myfunction(double U[][4])` and call it with `myfunction(U);`